# Adding a buildNumber in a jsp file

Tags: java, maven, jsp

I am trying to get the build number in a jsp file but for some reason the server doesn't deploy the app properly after I added a few entries in the pom. I see the build number but the app doesn't deploy now properly. Not sure if this is the right place to add the filtering for the build.jsp file.

I added these fields

```
<directory>${project.basedir}/WebContent/jsps</directory>
                    <targetPath>jsps</targetPath>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/build.jsp</include>
                    </includes>
```

pom

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>${project.name}${project.version}</warName>
                <webResources>
                    <webResource>
                        <directory>WebContent</directory>
                        <excludes>
                            <!-- exclude>images/**</exclude> <exclude>scripts/**</exclude> <exclude>styles/**</exclude -->
                            <exclude>assembly.xml</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/WebContent/jsps</directory>
                        <targetPath>jsps</targetPath>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/build.jsp</include>
                        </includes>
                    </webResource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, here I got the solution. I just needed to update the Maven Project and it worked and there is nothing wrong the pom.